# WCF Dataservices Insert into multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

So I have got my WCF Dataservice up and running, but I wanted to be able to insert into multiple tables - Would be easier to explain with a simple example:

Tables:

## tbl_Shop

- ShopID (primary key)
- Location
- Owner

## tbl_Products

- ProductID (primary key)
- ShopID
- ProductName
- ProductPrice

1 Shop has Many Products.
1 Product can only be associated with 1 Store.

I plan on using a stored proc to join and return tbl_Products and tbl_Shop on Shop_ID

I have a scenario where I want to:

- Step 1) Create a new entry in the tbl_Shop
- Step 2) Create a number of products and associate them with the Shop created in Step 1

What would be the best way to go about getting this setup?

I initially thought create an entry in tbl_Shop, return the ShopID of this newly created item and insert that when creating in tbl_Products - this seems like a messy/incorrect/unreliable way though.

I haven't set up an relationships between the tables (not sure if they are needed?)

Thanks

### EDIT:

I created the DB first, then generated a Model from it. In Model1.Designer.cs I have:

```
public partial class MyDBEntities3 : ObjectContext
{
   ....
```

In Service.svc I have:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class Service : DataService< MyDBEntities3>
{

    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {

        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 50);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;

        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead); 
        //set to false in production
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }



    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<GetRentByDate_Result> GetStoretByID(int ID)
    {
        // Calls a Stored Procedure which returns the store of a given StoreID
         return CurrentDataSource.GetRentByDate(ID).AsQueryable();
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you share your implementation of DbContext or ObjectContext? Are you using the WCF Data Services client? (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client)

Comment: Client will likely be javascript based such as AJAX.

Not sure what you mean by DBContext / Object COntext. At the moment I just have a basic WCF Data service based on Entity Framework model

Comment: To use EF, you need a class that inherits from ObjectContext or DbContext. If you used Code First, you created a class that inherits from DbContext. If you have an EDMX, you have an implementation of ObjectContext. At any rate, pasting your code for the class that inherits from DataService<T> would help.

Comment: I created the database first and generated the model from there. In the Model1.Designer.cs it says:

    public partial class MyDBEntities3 : ObjectContext. Have added details of the DataService<T> class above - is this the right one you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

In this case a foreign key relationship sounds right for you.
You don't say what flavour of SQL you are using, but something like this should do the trick:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Products
ADD CONSTRAINT [MY_FK] FOREIGN KEY([ShopID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_Shop]([ShopID])
```

The whole point of relationships to prevent problems with reliability etc.

---

Edit: Figuring out the ID of your new shop...

The easiest way is to create your shop table with an `IDENTITY` column
Something along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Shop
(
    ShopID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    Location VARCHAR(100)
    Owner VARCHAR(100)

)
```

Now, when you insert a row into tbl_Shop you must do something like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Shop (Location, Owner) SELECT 'Mars', 'Martian'
```

And to figure out the ShopID

```
DECLARE @SHOP INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY (assuming SQLServer 2008)
```

Then you can use that variable to insert into your Product table.

Comment: Ok thanks - once I add the the Foreign Key, how what would be the INSERT?

Comment: Assuming you have a shop with the following parameters: ShopID = 1, Location = 'Mars', Owner = 'Martian'. Your insert would simply be INSERT INTO [tbl_Products] SELECT 1,1 'MyProduct', '123'

Comment: But when I create the Shop how will I know which ID it is?
I want to create a Shop and then immediately after create some associated products.

Comment: Thanks TriggerPin - I will give this a go !

Answer (score 0):

To insert into multiple tables simultaneously using JavaScript, you will need to construct a ***deep insert*** payload and POST it to the service. This would probably be significantly easier if you use something like [data.js](http://datajs.codeplex.com/) to function as a client of the OData service.

That said, here's some steps you can try as a demonstration of how to do this in JavaScript:

1. Using Fiddler, do a GET to http://services.odata.org/(S(readwrite))/OData/OData.svc/Products.
2. Copy your session key from the response to that GET and use it in all future URLs.
3. POST the following payload to http://services.odata.org/(S([sessionkeythatyoucopied]))OData/OData.svc/Products (you should also set the Content-Type and Accept headers to application/json):

   {
      "_*metadata":{
         "type":"ODataDemo.Product"
      },
      "ID":0,
      "Description":"Fun to play with",
      "DiscontinuedDate":null,
      "Name":"Silly Putty",
      "Price":"4.25",
      "Rating":5,
      "ReleaseDate":"/Date(1343765403829)/",
      "Category":{
         "*_metadata":{
            "type":"ODataDemo.Category"
         },
         "ID":0,
         "Name":"Toys"
      }
   }
4. Examine the 201 Created response
5. Do a get from the Products and Categories entity sets to see the new entities.